# query from tables where table name is in the current query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query: 
`select main_value, subtable, subtable_column from table1`

I want to know can I query values from `subtable` at the same time that this query is running?

**EDIT
----**

table1 structure

```
main_value varchar
subtable varchar
subtable_column varchar
```

branches structure(subtable in the query)

```
id number
branch_name varchar
```

when I query from table1 and if got subtable's value as `branches`, and subtable_column's value as `branch_name` then query branch_name from branches.(becuase subtable column's value is branches retrieved from the query and column names vise versa).

**EDIT for tables and samples**
**---------------------------**

table1

```
+-----------------+--------------------+  
| Field           | Type               |  
+-----------------+--------------------+  
| ID              | number(20,0)       |  
| subtable        | varchar2(50 BYTE)  |  
| subtable_column | varchar2(100 BYTE) |  
+-----------------+--------------------+
```

branches

```
+-------------+-------------------+  
| Field       | Type              |  
+-------------+-------------------+  
| ID          | number(20,0)      |  
| branch_name | varchar2(50 BYTE) |  
+-------------+-------------------+
```

NB: these are just examples, so please dont suggest other ways rather than select from tables where table names and column names are in the current query at the same time.

i have records in table1 as below:

```
ID | subtable | subtable_column
-------------------------------
1  | branches | branch_nmae
2  | null     | null
```

and branches table as below:

```
ID | branch_name |
------------------
1  | new york
2  | colombo
```

### output:

```
+-------------+-------------------+---------------------------------+
| subtable    | subtable_column   | selected values from branches   |
+-------------+-------------------+---------------------------------+
| branches    | branch_name       | new york, colombo               |
| null        | null              |                                 |
+-------------+-------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, you can. What is structure of `table1` and `subtable`? Could you provide sample data and expected output? Do you want to run 2 query that get result from those 2 tables, or run 1 query to get data from those 2 tables?

Comment: Please read about *concurrency* in relational databases.

Comment: Joins (joins give you the "relational" in RDBMS) and subqueries (and more) allow one query to operate across many tables. I suggest a SQL tutorial: using joins should be very early in it.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach I updated the question

Comment: Plz provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach added sample output and other details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know all possible tables and all possible columns which table1 may contain then you could build query with `case when` containing all possibilities. Something like this:

```
select id, subtable, subtable_column, 
       case 
       when subtable = 'branches' and subtable_column = 'branch_name' then 
         (select listagg(branch_name, ', ') within group (order by branch_name) 
            from branches) 
       when subtable = 'branches' and subtable_column = 'id' then 
         (select listagg(id, ', ') within group (order by id) 
            from branches) 
       end as subtable_values
  from table1;
```

But more common solution for such problems is to use dynamic SQL. So write a function like here:

```
create or replace function get_subtable_values(i_table in varchar2, i_column in varchar2)
  return varchar2 is

  v_sql varchar2(32767);
  v_ret varchar2(32767);
begin
  if i_table is null then
    return null;
  end if;

  v_sql := 'select listagg('||i_column||', '', '') within group (order by null) from '||i_table;
  execute immediate v_sql into v_ret;
  return v_ret;
end;
```

... and use it in query:

```
select id, subtable, subtable_column, 
       get_subtable_values(subtable, subtable_column) as subtable_values
  from table1;
```

My test data and output for both queries:

```
create table table1(id, subtable, subtable_column) as (
    select 1, 'branches', 'branch_name' from dual union all
    select 2, 'branches', 'id'          from dual union all
    select 3, null,       null          from dual); 

create table branches(id, branch_name) as (
    select 1, 'New York' from dual union all
    select 2, 'Colombo'  from dual );
```

Result:

```
    ID  SUBTABLE  SUBTABLE_COLUMN  SUBTABLE_VALUES
------  --------  ---------------  --------------------
     1  branches  branch_name      Colombo, New York
     2  branches  id               1, 2
     3  null      null             null
```

I used function `listagg()` which glues all values into one string, comma separated. It's also possible to return table of varchars or user defined types. Of course there may be many issues like strings too long, data types other than varchar, exceptions should be handled, etc. But you see that's possible.

Comment: Excellent @Ponder! I would go with the dynamic query since I wanted to create a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
table1.id,
table1.subtable,
table1.subtable_column,
t.* 
FROM
table1
JOIN branches
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT group_concat( branch_name ) AS NAMES FROM branches ) AS t ON 1 = 1
```

this sql is ok，but it is  less efficient

Comment: Thing is i don't have the joined tabled name and its column names that i required to write a join clause before i quarried it.

Comment: you mean: no branches  and no branch_name ? And you want to get it ,like you output

Comment: sorry  ,I just understood. Let me think about it